# Can 3 women do dream rectification

Tags: halacha, women, tractate-brachot, sleep, dream

According to [the Shulchan Aruch OC 220:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.220.1) when one has a dream which makes them anxious, they can have 3 people rectify it.

My question is, can this be done by 3 women?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the 3 people in question were standing as a *beit din* (court), this would not work as the Shulchan Aruch ([CM 7:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.7.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) rules that women cannot be judges (see also section 2 [here](https://www.hakirah.org/Vol%2011%20Schachter.pdf)).

However this is not the case here. The [Kaf Hachaim 3 on OC 220:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.220.1?lang=bi&with=Kaf%20HaChayim&lang2=en) writes (my translation)

> לכתחלה יש לחזר אחר ג' גדולים ואם הם חכמים יותר טוב ואם לא אפשר בג'
> גדולים יש לצרף עמהם קטנים אם מבינים פי' המילות של הטבה:
>
> A priori, one should go in front of 3 adults, and it is better if they
> are learned, and if not possible to find 3 adults, one can add minors
> as long as they understand the words to be said [to rectify the
> dream].

From the fact minors as permitted, one sees this is not a formal *beit din* but instead a group of people (who ideally like the person who had the dream, see text of Shulchan Aruch). **If they can be minors then they can be women as well, and it is possible a woman might feel more comfortable rectifying her dream in front of other women friends.**

I checked the above with a Rosh Kollel from Bnei Brak but as always [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

Comment: לצרף could imply some adult men are necessary, though I'm not sure how deliberate the wording is considering עמהם implies 1 minor while קטנים implies 2.

Comment: Agree but the point was anyway that 3 men were not required.

Comment: Sounds a lot like zimun (OC 199), where some say you can include a discerning minor (but no more than one - MB), and women can make their own group, but it's best if they join 3 men.

Comment: @shmosel Who says it's better for them to join 3 men?

Comment: @DoubleAA That was my inference from רשות v. חובה, but I see now in SA HaRav that they're free to split off unless there are ten men.

Comment: I see @Deuteronomy's source offers the same argument (and also compares it to zimun).

Answer (score 2):

R. Elhanan Naftali Prins in Abhnei Derekh vol. 17, p. 96 analyzes this question:

[image]

Time permitting I'll translate at a later point.